# Domain Interface references NHibernate?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

Please see the question here, which I asked yesterday: [Domain Driven Design in an Onion Architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359405/domain-driven-design-in-an-onion-architecture)

As stated I understand that DDD is an approach that targets the domain layer only and Onion is an architecture for the entire system i.e. core, infrastructure etc.

Onion suggests that all interfaces in the application should be contained in the domain layer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861127/onion-architecture-business-services-interfaces-and-implementation and also described in my question from yesterday.

Now please see the Unit of Work interface here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55127/unit-of-work-repository-nhibernate.  Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
 public ISession Session { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
```

Therefore I have to create a UOW interface that has a reference to Session and a reference to SessionFactory.  Therefore I have to install NHibernate in the domain layer, which seems to be a big no no.

What can I do in this scenario? Please don't advise me not to put the interface in the domain layer as the domain layer contains a domain service similar to this one: http://www.zankavtaskin.com/2013/11/applied-domain-driven-design-ddd-part-4.html (Domain Services can access the database via a repository in a Domain Service).

Comment: Easy, just use persistence model in your _data_ assembly and map them to domain objects later on...

Comment: @kayess, onion states that domain should not reference infrastructure.

Comment: Well, there _must_ be something that needs to "see" the domain types, be it your mapper or an application service that does the job...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unit of Work *is* the transaction. The challenge is making sure the NHibernate interfaces and classes are not referenced outside of your data access layer. The unit of work interface should not have any NHibernate references, something like:

```cs
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Begin();
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

The concrete implementation of this interface could require something from NHibernate, for example:

```cs
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private ISession session;
    private ITransaction transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(session));
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        if (transaction != null)
            return;

        transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Rollback();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (transaction == null)
            return;

        transaction.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Dispose();
        transaction = null;
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (transaction == null)
            return;

        transaction.DiscardChanges();
        transaction.Dispose();
        transaction = null;
    }
}
```

The only references to NHibernate are in the constructor and private fields. A factory object will need to give you the unit of work, but your outside code should not need any references to NHibernate.

```cs
using (IUnitOfWork uow = unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
    uow.Begin();
    // do stuff
    uow.Commit();
}
```

In the code above, nothing is referencing NHibernate.

**The Unit of Work pattern gives you transaction control while decoupling the implementation of those transactions from the rest of the application.**

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  +1.  However, how is the session passed from the unit of work to the repository? The unit of work factory creates the unit of work, however unitOfWork.session is private.

Comment: @w0051977: I wouldn't pass the session from the unit of work to the repository. Some other thing needs to create the repository and unit of work so that other thing (the factory perhaps) has a reference to the NHibernate session.

Comment: Thanks.  They both have to use the same session.  Don't they?

Comment: @w0051977: yes, they both need to use the same session.

Comment: Thanks, so does unitOfWorkFactory have a method to create a repository (or multiple methods if there are multiple repositories) and a method to create a unit of work?

Comment: @w0051977: most likely, yes. In fact your domain layer would have the interface defined for the factory. Your data access layer would provide the implementing class.

Comment: In that case ISession would be a private instance variable in unitOfWorkFactory .  Would this be thread safe?

Comment: @w0051977: My code is not meant to be production worthy, but should give you the basic idea. Thread safety is something I will leave up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you said not to, I’m going to tell you that your use of ISession is an implementation detail, and should not be exposed to the domain layer.

The domain should be agnostic of how (or even if) your repository is physically persisting entities. ISession, as you say, is an NHibernate specific implement detail.

So how to solve? Well, your UoW interface should just expose just the methods it needs to do to accomplish its job, things like Commit() and BeginTransaction(), depending on what mode you prefer.  How it goes about committing might be implemented by an ISession under the hood, but not exposed in the interface.

Comment: Thanks, however BeginTransaction returns NHibernate.ITransaction, so a reference to NHibernate is still needed.  Isn't it?

Comment: No, the methods I was referring to would return only types your domain layer should know about.

Comment: So what does BeginTransaction return? Thanks

Comment: Whatever you want it to return. Depends on how you're going to use it.  The simplest thing would be to create an interface mirroring the calls you're going to make on the transaction object NHibernate exposes (not all it's public methods, just the ones you need), then implement your interface with a thin wrapper around the NHibernate one. Depending on your preferred, though, Begin transaction could return void and handle the details internally.

Comment: How can BeginTransaction return nothing.  It has to return an ITransaction so it can be disposed.  Doesn't it?

Comment: That depends entirely on your implementation.

Comment: @w0051977 the UnitOfWork implementation could just store the ITransaction in a field.